# how to construct stepper motor driver?

Tags: motor, driver, stepper-motor

I am going to do one project in labview
my requirement is to control the stepper motor in following way

while pressing one button in front panel  the stepper motor should run in one direction in  less than 30 RPM continuously.
 I have seen in USB 6008 specification we can only send digital I/O at 20mA.
But, my application require minimum one kg -cm torque, for that the stepper motor that I am having will draw more than 20mA...(probably 0.5 to 1 A)

and I don't know what exactly the stepper motor driver will do...
Can anyone elaborate the function of stepper motor driver ...?
Can stepper motor driver amplify the current pulses (digital output) to produce required torque?

Comment: Reading the L297 & L298 data sheets would provide a good introduction, even if you don't choose to use those chips.

Comment: What kind of stepper motor do you want to drive?

Answer (score 7):

Is your project the stepper motor driver, or is this for another, larger project?

Unless you specifically want to learn about the intricacies of driving stepper motors, I would recommend just buying an off-the-shell stepper driver, either in IC form, or completely assembled.

I'm a big fan of the [Allegro Micro stepper drivers.](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Motor-Driver-And-Interface-ICs/Bipolar-Stepper-Motor-Drivers.aspx)

If you want a simple, off-the-shelf solution, spark run offers a couple really inexpensive stepper-driver boards (seriously, they pretty much cost as much as the equivalent parts).

[image]
[image]
(Images are links)

They would be quite simple to interface with your USB DAQ system too. It would just take two DIO lines. One would set the direction, and the other would cause the motor to step - one step per cycle.

Comment: what about the cost of these kind of drivers

Comment: what is the maximum current rating of this driver .  i need 2A ouput

Comment: The current capability of each driver is listed on it's product page. (The images are links).

Comment: @Vijay - The question ultimately becomes 2A at what winding inductance and step rate?  At higher rate * inductance, it's necessary to use a driver voltage many times the rated motor voltage and use a PWM current-regulating "chopper" architecture in order to force rated current through the winding inductance quickly.  Otherwise the inductance means that current, and thus torque falls off rapidly with step speed and the motor may start skipping steps under load.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - both linked stepper drivers are "chopper" drivers.

Comment: @FakeName - yes, most IC drivers are, however most IC drivers have somewhat limited voltage range, which limits the effect of chopping with some motors, particularly older ones which may be relatively high impedance.  At high step speed voltage limit becomes an additional current limit.

Answer (score 3):

Controlling higher currents and voltages with the digital output is done using switches. Stepper motor driving is basically the same. It may change depending on your drive technique and stepper motor type, however it will be just your digital output to electronic switches that controls the windings.

Go to [here](http://www.kpsec.freeuk.com/trancirc.htm) and scroll down to "Using a transistor as a switch" to learn more about this. Also, [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Te5YYVZiOKs) is a great tutorial. Don't forget the flyback (kickback, freewheeling) diode. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXGtE3X2k7Y) is a video about that.

Also it is important to know your stepper motor type. Driving techniques differ by stepper motor and winding type, however the electronic switch theory remains the same.Here is a simple approach for a 5 or 6 wire, uni-polar stepper motor, when the transistors are powerful enough:

[image: Simple transistor stepper motor driver]

Using ICs like [ULN2003A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) is an easy solution. However, watch out for the current and voltage ratings. ULN2003A is a 500-mA-Rated Collector Current (Single Output). That means when only one channel (like 1B or 2B or 3B... in this case) is ON, it can supply a current of maximum 500mA. If you are not going to do half-stepping, that *may* suit your work. I once drove a stepper motor with this IC. Also, check out L297 & L298 as Chris Stratton suggested. Don't forget to check out L293D.

Comment: It's worth noting that the schematic shown requires a *unipolar* stepper motor.  If you have a bipolar-only stepper (recognizable as it only has 4 lead-wires), you will need a different driver setup.

Comment: Yes. I should add that there are different stepper motor types. Thanks.

Comment: it helps me to learn how to use transistor as switch

Comment: @vijay, Is this a good comment or bad? I mean, positively or negatively?

Comment: good only abdullah thanks yaar.... now i know how to amplify the current using transistor using ur source...my problem now is why we are using ic in stepper motor driver ...can u explain the function of some ic used in stepper motor driver....but thanks a lot for let me to see the valuable source about transistor... thats let me to learn more things

Comment: i am gonna use bipolar stepper motor....

Comment: are you from india, "yaar"? :) The ICs do the same job with discrete element circuits. However, they are integrated inside a chip that consumes less board space and lots of performance improvements as well as some protection. You can check the datasheets or Google to learn how to use the IC you have chosen.

Comment: ya i am from  india.... but my friend told apart from transistor , resistor etc we need ic thats y i am askin...

Comment: do u have gmail id which is use full for me to chat with u...if u wish....

Comment: how to find out RL in following calculation. i am gonna use stepper motor as load...the following is example to choose correct transistor.(from the link u have given)
The supply voltage is 6V for both the IC and load. The IC can supply a maximum current of 5mA.
Load current = Vs/RL = 6/100 = 0.06A = 60mA, so transistor must have Ic(max) > 60mA.
The maximum current from the IC is 5mA, so transistor must have hFE(min) > 60 (5 × 60mA/5mA).
Choose general purpose low power transistor BC182 with Ic(max) = 100mA and hFE(min) = 100.
RB = 0.2 × RL × hFE = 0.2 × 100 × 100 = 2000. so choose RB = 1k8

Comment: Won't switching on one transistor on a winding cause the other end to try to swing up to twice the supply voltage, and won't clamping the voltage to 1x the supply voltage cause considerable stress on the transistor, diode, and motor?  I would think the clamp diodes should be connected to a point which is allowed to float up to 2x the supply voltage (if desired, one could have the clamp diodes all connect to a capacitor; trying to draw the capacitor below 2x vdd would waste power, but if the cap voltage exceeds 2x vdd, excess energy could be harvested "for free").

Comment: supercat ..i cant understand what u r telling

Comment: @supercat, why does the other end try to swing up to 2xsupply?

Comment: @abdullahkahraman: The motor will have some tentency to act like a center-tap transformer.  In an ideal center-tap transformer, the voltage and current in both sides will be equal (so a clamp diode preventing one side from going above VDD+0.7V would prevent the other from going below VDD+0.7V).  A motor won't behave as an ideal transformer, of course, but it will still show that effect to some degree.

Comment: @supercat, where can I learn more detailed info on this? How to search? What is the topic?

Comment: @vijay, there is a chat system built into the site but if you have a fuller question please post it as a new question with full details of what you need to know. Often formulating a question on its own can do the larger part of resolving an issue of understanding.